# Where does ImageCollage place each image?

Tags: image-processing

How can I get the bounding box of each image of a collage made by ImageCollage? This would be useful, for example, to use the collage as an image map on a web site.

I couldn't find a way to query ImageCollage for the placements directly.

An indirect method is creating constant-color images with the same dimensions as the original images, call ImageCollage on those constant images and then extract the bounding boxes.

For example, suppose the dimensions of the images made into a collage are

```
imageDimensions = (SeedRandom[123]; Table[RandomInteger[{100, 300}, 2], {5}]);
```

Create a collage of constant-color images with these dimensions:

```
colors = ColorData[3] /@ Range[Length@imageDimensions];
images = MapThread[ConstantImage, {colors, imageDimensions}];
collage = ImageCollage[images, Background -> Transparent];
```

Get the bounding boxes:

```
boundingBoxes = CoordinateBoundingBox@ImageValuePositions[collage, #] & /@ colors
```

Is there a more direct way to find the placement that ImageCollage selects for each image?

Comment: The ”Mathematica way” would have been for `ImageCollage` to have a `Regions` option like `Rasterize`, unfortunately, it seems to not have been implemented.

Comment: Does your method satisfy all your situations?Does it have `bug` in more cases?

Comment: It works in the few cases I tried. The method requires each images in the collage to have a distinct color. So if many images, change ColorData[3] to one with more alternatives. It would be nicer to get the regions directly rather than having to run ImageCollage twice and extract all points of each color. This assumes ImageCollage only uses the image dimensions, not the image content, to place the images.