# Image Collage with equal-sized labels

Tags: image-processing, scaling

I've been trying to make an image collage, where each image in the collage has a text label in the lower-right corner (or wherever really), where the text is all the same size. Can't seem to make it work.
For example, if I want to use some  [images of the Earth from Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_first_images_of_Earth_from_space), I can create a simple collage in Mathematica, and then go to a image editor to add text manually, resulting in:
[image: A collage]

The goal would be to have images automatically labelled. If I try to add labels during the creation of the collage though, all the text is rescaled as well.

Comment: Please provide the code you are using to create the collage. It will be easier to help you this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me post a fragile answer to this question. I will also point out the current shortcomings as I go along.
Assuming you have photos already imported, let's put them in a list. Also make a list with labels.

```
imgs = {im1, im2, im3, im4, im5, im6};
imgLabels = {"one", "two", "BlueDot", "four", "five", "space"};

t = ImageCollage[imgs, ImagePadding -> 5, Background -> White, 
  Method -> "Rows"]
```

[image]

**ImagePadding** with a white background (why?) I will need to detect corners. At this point you can choose a more appropriate background depending on the images. First make a mask.

```
mask = Binarize[MaxDetect[t, 0.001] // DeleteSmallComponents]
```

[image]

Using this following bit from the docs:

```
strong = ImageCorners[mask, 5, .005, 5];
weak = Complement[ImageCorners[mask, 1, .0005], strong];
HighlightImage[t,
 {AbsolutePointSize[3], Red, Legended[weak, "weak"],
  Green, AbsolutePointSize[10], Legended[strong, "strong"]}]
```

[image]

**tinkered** with the `weak` and `strong` till I got good results. The points called `strong` are a list of points.

```
{{7.5, 945.5}, {524.5, 945.5}, {944.5, 945.5}, {7.5, 534.5}, {544.5, 
  534.5}, {1086.5, 534.5}, {7.5, 549.5}, {524.5, 549.5}, {944.5, 
  549.5}, {7.5, 7.5}, {544.5, 7.5}, {1086.5, 7.5}, {1455.5, 
  945.5}, {1455.5, 549.5}, {1455.5, 534.5}, {1455.5, 7.5}, {509.5, 
  549.5}, {929.5, 549.5}, {529.5, 7.5}, {1071.5, 7.5}, {509.5, 
  945.5}, {929.5, 945.5}, {529.5, 534.5}, {1071.5, 534.5}}
```

I detect the upper left corners.

```
uleftcorners = (#[[
      1 ;; ;; 2]] & /@ (GatherBy[
       Sort[GatherBy[Sort@strong, Last][[2 ;; ;; 2]]], First] // 
      Flatten[#, 1] &)) // Flatten[#, 1] &
Show[t, Graphics[{Red, PointSize -> Large, Point /@ uleftcorners}, 
  ImageSize -> Large]]
```

[image]

That's where the labels will go. Nudge these down and right a bit to get label positions.

```
lablpos = # + {20, -30} & /@ uleftcorners
```

`g1` is a `Graphics` with just the labels in yellow with **no guarantees** that these will not obscure something on the image. Now you can either use the collage with or without padding (in my case, called `tnopadding`) in which case you will have to **adjust** the label positions slightly.

```
g1 = Graphics[{Table[{Yellow, 
      Text[Style[imgLabels[[i]], 12, Bold], lablpos[[i]]]}, {i, 1, 
      Length@imgLabels}]}, ImageSize -> Large];

Show[tnopadding, g1]
```

[image]

The labels as you can see are not applied to the right picture. This is because (afaik) the `ImageCollage` does not provide information on the bounding box locations for each image. However you can always change the labels around in the list and reevaluate `g1` only.

In short:

- Background on collage (to help with the mask); this step could be more challenging depending on the colors present in the images
- No information provided on placement of images within the `ImageCollage` so corners must be extracted; Tinkering to get the `strong` image corners. There is a previous [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220543/where-does-imagecollage-place-each-image) that discusses it, so you can take a look at that.
- I tried "Columns" option and also different weights for the images in the collage. You should also do that.
- Text color will have to be chosen manually depending on the color of the images. Using `Style`, this can be done separately for each picture.

In short, it was lots of fun. It will save you some time not having to place labels manually, but unfortunately does not deliver a fully automated solution for attaching picture names. However, the workaround isn't that difficult to use either.

Comment: Cool! I guess it's a method working around the ImageCollage formatting, but it gets it done well. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the accept. I recall that @kglr showed a method where you can use locators to put labels. Thinking in retrospect, that type of solution would be better regardless of image collage picture placement. This one is limited to `Columns` and `Rows` placements.